# how to handle master page's panels in facade pattern style

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

i have master page that have no panels. i would like to use facade pattern to view appropriate panel or set of panel while user clicks link button of content place holder page.

while on first account load (Initial state),first panel will be visible and others are off,
while user clicks link button of landing page, second panel visible and others are off.

how ever i create this base class newManageClass:

```
public class newManageClass : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public Panel Panel_User_Photo { get; set; }
        public Panel Panel_Search { get; set; }
        public Panel Panel_notification { get; set; }
        public Panel Panel_companymanagement { get; set; }
        public Panel Panel_omwealthmanagement { get; set; }
        public Panel Panel_newsletter { get; set; }

        public newManageClass()
        {
            Panel_User_Photo = new Panel();
            Panel_Search = new Panel();
            Panel_notification = new Panel();
            Panel_companymanagement = new Panel();
            Panel_omwealthmanagement = new Panel();
            Panel_newsletter = new Panel();
        }
        public void OnPageLoad()
        {
            Panel_User_Photo.Visible = true;
            Panel_Search.Visible = true;
            Panel_notification.Visible = true;
            Panel_companymanagement.Visible = false;
            Panel_omwealthmanagement.Visible = false;
            Panel_newsletter.Visible = false;
        }
        public void CompanyManagementClick()
        {
            Panel_User_Photo.Visible = false;
            Panel_Search.Visible = true;
            Panel_companymanagement.Visible = true;
            Panel_notification.Visible = false;
            Panel_omwealthmanagement.Visible = false;
            Panel_newsletter.Visible = false;
        }
        public void OmWealthManagementClick()
        {
            Panel_User_Photo.Visible = false;
            Panel_Search.Visible = true;
            Panel_notification.Visible = false;
            Panel_companymanagement.Visible = false;
            Panel_omwealthmanagement.Visible = true;
            Panel_newsletter.Visible = false;
        }
        public void NewsLetterManagementClick()
        {
            Panel_User_Photo.Visible = false;
            Panel_Search.Visible = false;
            Panel_notification.Visible = false;
            Panel_companymanagement.Visible = false;
            Panel_omwealthmanagement.Visible = false;
            Panel_newsletter.Visible = true;
        }
        public void UserManagementClick()
        {
            Panel_User_Photo.Visible = false;
            Panel_Search.Visible = true;
            Panel_notification.Visible = false;
            Panel_companymanagement.Visible = false;
            Panel_omwealthmanagement.Visible = false;
            Panel_newsletter.Visible = false;
        }
        protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreInit(e);
            if (Session["MyTheme"] == null)
            {
                Session.Add("MyTheme", "blue");
                Page.Theme = ((string)Session["MyTheme"]);
            }
            else
            {
                Page.Theme = ((string)Session["MyTheme"]);
            }
        }
    }
```

after all that i implement this class as helper class to master page:

```
 using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Configuration;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Security;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
    using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml;
    public partial class Admin_MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        newManageClass manage_panels = new newManageClass();
        DateTime LastCheck = DateTime.MinValue;
        struct UnreadMails
        {
            //public string From { get; set; }
            private string _From;
            public string From
            {
                get { return _From; }
                set { _From = value; }
            }
            //public string Subject { get; set; }
            private string _Subject;
            public string Subject
            {
                get { return _Subject; }
                set { _Subject = value; }
            }
            //public DateTime MailModify { get; set; }
            private DateTime _MailModify;
            public DateTime MailModify
            {
                get { return _MailModify; }
                set { _MailModify = value; }
            }
        }
        Collection<UnreadMails> GetNewMails()
        {
            WebRequest webGmailRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom");
            webGmailRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;

            NetworkCredential loginCredentials = new NetworkCredential("XXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXX");
            webGmailRequest.Credentials = loginCredentials;

            WebResponse webGmailResponse = webGmailRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream strmUnreadMailInfo = webGmailResponse.GetResponseStream();

            StringBuilder sbUnreadMailInfo = new StringBuilder(); byte[] buffer = new byte[8192]; int byteCount = 0;

            while ((byteCount = strmUnreadMailInfo.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                sbUnreadMailInfo.Append(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, byteCount));

            XmlDocument UnreadMailXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            UnreadMailXmlDoc.LoadXml(sbUnreadMailInfo.ToString());
            XmlNodeList UnreadMailEntries = UnreadMailXmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("entry");

            UnreadMails oUnreadMails = new UnreadMails();
            Collection<UnreadMails> clUnreadMails = new Collection<UnreadMails>();

            for (int _i = 0; _i < UnreadMailEntries.Count; ++_i)
            {
                oUnreadMails.Subject = (UnreadMailEntries[_i]["title"]).InnerText;
                oUnreadMails.From = (UnreadMailEntries[_i]["author"])["name"].InnerText + " <" + (UnreadMailEntries[_i]["author"])["email"].InnerText + ">";
                oUnreadMails.MailModify = DateTime.Parse((UnreadMailEntries[_i]["modified"]).InnerText);
                clUnreadMails.Add(oUnreadMails);
            }
            return clUnreadMails;
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
manage_panels.Panel_User_Photo = (Panel)this.Page.Master.FindControl("Panel_User_Photo");
    manage_panels.Panel_Search = (Panel)this.Page.Master.FindControl("Panel_Search");
    manage_panels.Panel_notification = (Panel)this.Page.Master.FindControl("Panel_notification");
    manage_panels.Panel_companymanagement = (Panel)this.Page.Master.FindControl("Panel_companymanagement");
    manage_panels.Panel_omwealthmanagement = (Panel)this.Page.Master.FindControl("Panel_omwealthmanagement");
    manage_panels.Panel_newsletter = (Panel)this.Page.Master.FindControl("Panel_newsletter");

string fullPath = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fullPath);
            switch (fileName)
            {
                case "Inquiry_history.aspx":
                    manage_panels.OnPageLoad();
                    break;
                case "manage_companies.aspx":
                    manage_panels.CompanyManagementClick();
                    break;
                case "service_manage.aspx":
                    manage_panels.OmWealthManagementClick();
                    break;
                case "subscriber_manage.aspx":
                    manage_panels.NewsLetterManagementClick();
                    break;
                case "user_manage.aspx":
                    manage_panels.UserManagementClick();
                    break;
                default:
                    manage_panels.OnPageLoad();
                    break;
            }
            if (Session["username"] == null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                {
                    manage_panels.OnPageLoad();
                    using (SqlConnection conn = Util.GetConnection())
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        string select = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_FreeTrial_History WHERE ((MONTH(Created_date)=DATEPART(month,GETDATE()) AND DAY(Created_date)= DATEPART(day,GETDATE()) AND YEAR(Created_date)= DATEPART(year,GETDATE())))";
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select, conn);
                        int nResult;
                        nResult = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                        lbl_free_count.Text = nResult.ToString();
                        string select1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_Inquiry_History WHERE IsRead='False'";
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(select1, conn);
                        int nResult1;
                        nResult1 = int.Parse(cmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                        lbl_service_count.Text = nResult1.ToString();
                    }
                    string name, email, birth_date, phone_no, address, occuption, password, city_name, pin, counry_id, state_id;
                    int profile_id;
                    DatabaseHelper.GetUserProfile(Session["username"].ToString(), out name, out profile_id, out password, out email, out phone_no, out address, out birth_date, out occuption, out counry_id, out state_id, out city_name, out pin);
                    lbldisplayname.Text = name;
                    int NewUnreadMail = 0;
                    DateTime LastUnreadMailDate = DateTime.MinValue;
                    Collection<UnreadMails> clUnreadMails = GetNewMails();
                    for (int i = 0; i < clUnreadMails.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (clUnreadMails[i].MailModify > LastCheck)
                        {
                            NewUnreadMail++;
                        }
                        if (clUnreadMails[i].MailModify > LastUnreadMailDate)
                            LastUnreadMailDate = clUnreadMails[i].MailModify;
                    }
                    LastCheck = LastUnreadMailDate;
                    lblnewunreadmail.Text = NewUnreadMail.ToString();
                }
            }

        protected void SiteMapPath1_ItemCreated(object sender, SiteMapNodeItemEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == SiteMapNodeItemType.Root || (e.Item.ItemType == SiteMapNodeItemType.PathSeparator && e.Item.ItemIndex == 1))
            {
                e.Item.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        protected void lbtnlogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session.Clear();
            Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx");
        }
        protected void hplhome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Admin_Landing_page.aspx");
            manage_panels.OnPageLoad();
        }
    }
```

and this is admin_landing_page.aspx code:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class Admin_Admin_Landing_page : newManageClass
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["username"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("../Default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            OnPageLoad();
        }
    }
    protected void lbut_manage_inquiry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("Inquiry_history.aspx");
        OnPageLoad();
    }
    protected void lbut_company_management_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("manage_companies.aspx");
        CompanyManagementClick();
    }
    protected void lbut_stocksmanagement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("service_manage.aspx");
        OmWealthManagementClick();
    }
    protected void lbut_newslettermanagement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("subscriber_manage.aspx");
        NewsLetterManagementClick();
    }
    protected void lbut_usermanagement_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("user_manage.aspx");
        UserManagementClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Panel_notification = new Panel();` will not work. you have to add the control to the page. something like `Page.Controls.Add(Panel_notification)`

Comment: i use this technique in master page code file. but error occured like Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: and can i commented this newManageClass contructor code.

Comment: no, keep it as it is.

Comment: you are creating a new instance of `newManageClass` in your `admin_landing_page.aspx.cs`. but you have to use the instance you created in your `Admin_masterpage.cs` file.

Comment: ya i update my quetion and i follow ur steps. but error still occured like Object reference not set to an instance of an object from master page constructor. for more error info i include error details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but here's what I tried

### **newManageClass.cs**

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public class newManageClass
{
    public Panel Panel1 { get; set; }    
    public Panel Panel2 { get; set; }    
    public Panel Panel3 { get; set; }

    public void OnPageLoad()
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        Panel2.Visible = true;
        Panel3.Visible = true;
    }

    public void button1()
    {
        Panel1.Visible = true;
        Panel2.Visible = false;
        Panel3.Visible = false;
    }

    public void button2()
    {
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        Panel2.Visible = true;
        Panel3.Visible = false;
    }

    public void button3()
    {
        Panel1.Visible = false;
        Panel2.Visible = false;
        Panel3.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

### **Admin_Masterpage.master**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Admin_MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="Admin_MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BackColor="Red" Height="50px">abc</asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" BackColor="Green" Height="50px">def</asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" BackColor="Blue" Height="50px">ghi</asp:Panel>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### **Admin_Masterpage.master.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Admin_MasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["MyTheme"] == null)
        {
            Session.Add("MyTheme", "blue");
            Page.Theme = ((string)Session["MyTheme"]);
        }
        else
        {
            Page.Theme = ((string)Session["MyTheme"]);
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

### **Admin_Landing_Page.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Admin_MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Admin_Landing_Page.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_Landing_Page" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:Button ID="btn1" runat="server" Text="Button1" OnClick="btn1_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn2" runat="server" Text="Button2" OnClick="btn2_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn3" runat="server" Text="Button3" OnClick="btn3_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

### **Admin_Landing_Page.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Admin_Landing_Page : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    newManageClass cls = new newManageClass();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cls.Panel1 = this.Page.Master.FindControl("Panel1") as Panel;
        cls.Panel2 = this.Page.Master.FindControl("Panel2") as Panel;
        cls.Panel3 = this.Page.Master.FindControl("Panel3") as Panel;
    }
    protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cls.button1();
    }
    protected void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cls.button2();
    }
    protected void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cls.button1();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ShalinGajjar, did you comment out the three lines inside `newManageClass` constructor? And please update your question and add the code of the `aspx` page you are calling.

Comment: ok.i comment out these line and update my question and include full code of my master page so u can understand.

Comment: How ever Only OnPageLoad() works fine but LinkButton of Admin_Landing_Page not works perfactly. can u help me please

Comment: @ShalinGajjar, it will not work if you call your methods after `Response.Redirect`. move the calls to `Admin_Masterpage.master.cs` **Page_Load** method. check `Request.Url` to see which page is loading and call the appropriate method. like `if(Request.Url.Contains("manage_companies.aspx")) CompanyManagementClick();`